# Issues with os.listdir when script is an executable

Tags: shell, executable

I have created a script that takes a file from one folder and produces another file in another folder. This is a project to convert one format into another to be used by people who dont have strong background in informatics so I have created a folder with the script plus the input folder and the output folder. The user just need to put the input file in the input folder and take the results from the output folder.

The script works fine if I run this python script when running with visual code as well as If I run the script using the terminal ( python CSVtoVCFv3.py )

but when I convert my script in an executable with pyinstaller I found the next error.

```
 File "CSVtoVCFv3.py", line 99, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/manoldominguez/input/'
[99327] Failed to execute script CSVtoVCFv3
```

The code used in line 99 is:

```
97 actual_path = os.getcwd()
98 folder_input = '/input/'
99 input_file_name = os.listdir(actual_path+folder_input)
100 input_file_name= ''.join(input_file_name)
101 CSV_input = actual_path+folder_input+input_file_name
```

I have also tried this:

```
actual_path = (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('CSVtoVCFv3.py')))
```

So as conclusion as far as I can understand the issue is:

In these lines If I run my script I get this

```
'/Users/manoldominguez/Desktop/CSVtoVCF/input/'
```

If my script is ran with my executable I get this

```
'/Users/manoldominguez/input/'
```

Comment: That looks like a python programming issue, not a Unix/Linux one. Anyway, check the result of `os.getcwd()` and how you invoke the python program.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo 
os.getcwd() give me back '/Users/manoldominguez/Desktop/CSVtoVCF'

Comment: Thanks ajgringo619. I will do.

Comment: Consider using `os.path.join()` instead of concatenating strings

Comment: rather `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` or `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv))`

Comment: `os.getcwd()` gives `Current Working Directory` - it means folder in which script was started, not folder in which script is saved. And then you have to use code in commend above to get path to folder with script.

Answer (score 0):

`os.getcwd()` gives `Current Working Directory` - it means folder in which script was executed, but it doesn't have to be folder in which script is saved. This way you can run code in different folder and it works with files in different folder - and it can be usefull.

But if you need with files in folder where you have script then you can get this folder using

```
SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

or

```
import sys

SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

not with `'CSVtoVCFv3.py'`

And then you can join it

```
 SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

 folder_input = '/input/'

 full_folder_input = os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, folder_input)

 all_filenames = os.listdir(full_folder_input)

 for input_file_name in all_filenames:
     #CSV_input = os.path.join(full_folder_input, input_file_name)
     CSV_input = os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, folder_input, input_file_name)
```

I only don't like your

```
 input_file_name = os.listdir(actual_path+folder_input)
 input_file_name= ''.join(input_file_name)
```

because `listdir()` may gives more files and then your `join` may create incorrect path. Better get `input_file_name[0]` for single file or use `for`-loop to work with all files in folder.

---

BTW: Maybe you should use `sys.argv` to get path as parameter and then everyone may decide where to put file.